# Target health check fails - AWS Network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kops

NOTE: I tried to include screenshots but stackoverflow does not allow me to add images with preview so I included them as links.

I deployed a web app on AWS using kOps.
I have two nodes and set up a Network Load Balancer.

[image]
The target group of the NLB has two nodes (each node is an instance made from the same template).

[image]
Load balancer actually seems to be working after checking ingress-nginx-controller logs.
The requests are being distributed over pods correctly. And I can access the service via ingress external address.
But when I go to AWS Console / Target Group, one of the two nodes is marked as  and I am concerned with that.

Nodes are running correctly.
[image]

I tried to execute sh into nginx-controller and tried curl to both nodes with their internal IP address.
For the healthy node, I get nginx response and for the unhealthy node, it times out.
I do not know how nginx was installed on one of the nodes and not on the other one.

Could anybody let me know the possible reasons?

Comment: Can you share the service object? My guess is that you are using ExternalTrafficPolicy: local, and that both your nginx instances run on the same node. If so, this is correct behavior.

Comment: @OleMarkusWith Yes, I found that it's set to local by default. I would accept David's answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem before and this should be documented somewhere on AWS or Kubernetes. The answer is copied from [AWS Premium Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-unhealthy-worker-node-nginx/)

#### Short description

The NGINX Ingress Controller sets the `spec.externalTrafficPolicy` option to `Local` to preserve the client IP. Also, requests aren't routed to unhealthy worker nodes. The following troubleshooting implies that you don't need to maintain the cluster IP address or preserve the client IP address.

#### Resolution

If you check the ingress controller service you will see the `External Traffic Policy` field set to `Local`.

```
$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx describe svc ingress-nginx-controller

Output:

Name:                     ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
...
External Traffic Policy:  Local
...
```

This Local setting drops packets that are sent to Kubernetes nodes that aren't running instances of the NGINX Ingress Controller. Assign NGINX pods (from the Kubernetes website) to the nodes that you want to schedule the NGINX Ingress Controller on.

Update the pec.externalTrafficPolicy option to `Cluster`

```
$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx patch service ingress-nginx-controller -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Cluster"}}'

Output:
service/ingress-nginx-controller patched
```

By default, NodePort services perform source address translation (from the Kubernetes website). For NGINX, this means that the source IP of an HTTP request is always the IP address of the Kubernetes node that received the request. If you set a NodePort to the value of the externalTrafficPolicy field in the ingress-nginx service specification to Cluster, then you can't maintain the source IP address.

Comment: Perfect! It shows all healthy now, thanks!

Comment: Make sure that `Cluster` is actually what you want though. If you e.g want to see client IPs in the nginx logs, you need this to be `Local`. And the unhealthy instance is by design. The better way of getting them healthy is to use topology spread constraints to ensure the nginx pods are distributed evenly.

Comment: Thanks, Ole. At the moment, there's a deadline pressure and I will just let it be Cluster for now. I do not follow what you say because I do not have much knowledge. I will surely try after some investigation later. Thanks again.

Comment: Also check if you have a taint on your nodes. It will prevent the nginx controllers from being scheduled,thus their state will be unhealthy.